# pundit rspec - uninitialized constant UserPolicy, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, rspec-rails, pundit

Looking for some help, Im a noob to Rspec and pundit, I was following an example to setup pundit and have the testing of it, but all the test are failing with

```
NameError:
  uninitialized constant UserPolicy
# ./spec/policies/user_policy_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

Need some help to figure out why as I have no idea :(

Using:

- Rails 5.1.6
- RSpec 3.7

  - rspec-core 3.7.1
  - rspec-expectations 3.7.0
  - rspec-mocks 3.7.0
  - rspec-rails 3.7.2
  - rspec-support 3.7.1
- Pundit 1.1.0
- Devise 4.4.3

**config/initializers/pundit.rb**

```
module PunditHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Pundit
    rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
  end

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = "Access denied."
    redirect_to (request.referrer || root_path)
  end

end

ApplicationController.send :include, PunditHelper
```

**app/policies/user_policy.rb**

```
class UserPolicy
  include ApplicationHelper

  attr_reader :current_user, :model

  def initialize(current_user, model)
    @current_user = current_user
    @user = model
  end

  def index?
    is_admin?(@current_user)
  end

  def show?
    is_admin?(@current_user) or @current_user == @user
  end

  def update?
    is_admin?(@current_user) or @current_user == @user 
  end

  def destroy?
    is_admin?(@current_user) or @current_user == @user
  end

end
```

**spec/support/pundit.rb**

```
require 'pundit/rspec'
```

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if 
Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
...
```

**spec/policies/user_policy_spec.rb**

```
describe UserPolicy do
  subject { UserPolicy }

  let (:current_user) { FactoryBot.build_stubbed :user }
  let (:other_user) { FactoryBot.build_stubbed :user }
  let (:admin) { FactoryBot.build_stubbed :user, :admin }

  permissions :index? do
    it "denies access if not an admin" do
      expect(user_policy).not_to permit(current_user)
    end
    it "allows access for an admin" do
      expect(user_policy).to permit(admin)
    end
  end

end
```

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include Pundit
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def index
    @users = User.all
    authorize User
  end
  ....

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your're missing the require line for 'rails_helper' in your user_policy_spec file

`require 'rails_helper'`